# Installing MariaDB 10.4 on Centos 7

Tags: centos, mariadb

I am experiencing some trouble with installing MariaDB 10.4 on Centos 7. The official [mariaDB guide](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#distro=CentOS&distro_release=centos7-ppc64le--centos7&mirror=rackspace&version=10.4) says that a new repo file `MariaDB.repo` should created in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` with the contents of:

```
# MariaDB 10.4 CentOS repository list - created 2019-12-13 22:03 UTC
# http://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-ppc64le
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

I've run `yum-config-manager --enable  MariaDB.repo` and `yum update` and inspected the enabled repos:

```
$ enabled | grep maria
mariadb          MariaDB              86
```

This confirms that the new repo is enabled. The guide later says to run `sudo yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client`. Unfortunately, there is nothing to install as I am greeted with a message:

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.anexia.at
 * epel: ftp.uni-kl.de
 * extras: mirror.easyname.at
 * remi-php74: remi.mirror.karneval.cz
 * remi-safe: remi.mirror.karneval.cz
 * updates: centos.anexia.at
No package MariaDB-server available.
  * Maybe you meant: mariadb-server
No package MariaDB-client available.
```

Notice that there is no mention of `MariaDB.repo` I just enabled. Also, the suggested package `mariadb-server` is version 5.5. What is the correct way to install MariaDB version 10.4 on Centos 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is to replace line:

```
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-ppc64le
```

with

```
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-amd64
```

The first line point to packages for [PowerPC architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC). The second to x86 architecture

To explicitly enable this repo add this:

```
enabled=1
```

and then try to install

Comment: Thanks! You mean centos7-amd64, right? I also tried that and no MariaDB-server is found

Comment: @sanjihan you can add one more line to the repo file. WIll edit it in answer

Comment: Even after explicitly enabling it in .repo, I still only get `mariadb-server.x86_64    1:5.5.64-1.el7     base` in response to `yum list MariaDB-server`

Comment: try to install line this: `yum install MariaDB-server-10.4.11`

Comment: `No package MariaDB-server-10.4.11 available.` :(

Comment: Did you edit the repo file? http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-server-10.4.11-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm

Comment: yes. I just tested it on another machine and the same procedure worked without problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102191/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-sanjihan).